# Trying to paste images into a grid using PIL - Python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm fairly new to Python, so apologies in advance for any stupidity. My objective is to take a set of square images and want to plot these into a n x n grid with no spacing in-between. I've some what been able to achieve this but I feel there is a much more efficient way, which handles multiple scenarios and dimensions. It may be that there are other modules are more suited, however at the moment I know of Pillow so attempting to use this.

Current approach with a 2100 x 2100 image where sample_list is a list of 700 x 700 images:

```
positions = [(0,0),
            (0,700),
            (0,1400),
            (700,0),
            (700,700),
            (700,1400),
            (1400,0),
            (1400,700),
            (1400,1400)]

a = Image.new('LA', (2100,2100))
counter = 0

for i in sample_list:
    a.paste(i, positions[counter])
    counter += 1
```

Any help would be massive appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generalize your a code by setting up parameters like number of images, image sizes, etc. in the beginning. Then, you can generate that `positions` list without hardcoding any values.

Here's some code:

```py
from itertools import product
from math import isqrt
from PIL import Image

# Parameters
width = 600
height = 700
n_images = 9

# Dummy sample list of images
sample_list = [Image.new('LA', (width, height), (int(i/n_images*255), 255)) for i in range(n_images)]

# Determine positions from given parameters
x_pos = [i * width for i in range(isqrt(n_images))]
y_pos = [i * height for i in range(isqrt(n_images))]
positions = list(product(x_pos, y_pos))

# Build and save final image
a = Image.new('LA', (width * isqrt(n_images), height * isqrt(n_images)))
for i, img in enumerate(sample_list):
    a.paste(img, positions[i])
a.save('img.png')
```

That'd be the output:

[image: Output]

Notice: `n_images` must be square number.

`math.isqrt` is the integer square root. And, `itertools.product` gives the Cartesian product of the elements from two lists, i.e. all combinations from both lists' elements.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.5
Pillow:      8.1.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you for this - great answer which has taught me a few things I didn't know! Thank you!!